# Opening External URL in salesforce tab upon button click, the information is not visible

Tags: lightning

I am trying to open an external url (say a particular wiki page) in one of the tabs inside salesforce on click of a button.

I have added "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" in **CSP trusted sites** & I used the follow code in the onClick function:

```
var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
workspaceAPI.openTab({
       url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salesforce.com",
       focus: true
})
```

A tab is opening on the button click, but the tab is blank with no information.

Error: Refused to  display  in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Answer (score 0):

He Nidhi.  That's actually an error that's based on the other server's settings:  It's set not to allow its pages to be displayed in an iFrame on a page that isn't in the same domain as the page you're loading.

As far as I know, there isn't a way around this...and even if there were, we should respect the author's desire.

Sorry for the bad news.  :(

Comment: Hey Nidhi -- were you able to find another solution?